# SQL script in R giving only limited number of observation

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I'm running SQL Script in R Studio and connecting to SAP HANA server. Every time, I run the script it only gives me limited observations. Sometime, I get 800 observations, and sometime 1000 observations. 
When run this SQL Script in Tableau or in SSMS, I'm getting million observations.

Can anyone help, why R is giving only limited rows?

Below is the code I'm using

```
library(RODBC)

ch <- odbcConnect('HANAxxx',uid='xxxxx',pwd='xxxxx', DBMSencoding="UTF-8")

fiscqtr <- as.character(20191)
begqtr <- as.character(201901)
endqtr <- as.character(201913)
avginvBOP <- as.character(201850)
avginvEOP <- as.character(as.numeric(endqtr)-1)
eopweek <- endqtr
receiptstart <- as.character(201850)
receiptend <- as.character(as.numeric(endqtr)-2)

sales <- sqlQuery(ch, paste('SELECT

                            mat."DIVISION_TXT" AS Division_Name,
                            mat."DEPARTMENT_TXT" AS Department_Name,
                            mat."CLASS_TXT" AS Class_Name,
                            mat."yz_abc1" AS Base_Style_ID,
                            mat."yz_abc1_TXT" AS Base_Style_Name,
                            mat."COLOR" AS Color_Code,
                            mat."COLOR_TXT" AS Color_Name,

                            SUM(CASE WHEN (r."ZWEEK" BETWEEN \'',begqtr,'\' AND \'',endqtr,'\') THEN r."SALES" ELSE 0 END) AS NET_SLS$,
                            SUM(CASE WHEN (r."ZWEEK" BETWEEN \'',begqtr,'\' AND \'',endqtr,'\') THEN r."COST" ELSE 0 END) AS NET_SLSC,
                            SUM(CASE WHEN (r."ZWEEK" BETWEEN \'',begqtr,'\' AND \'',endqtr,'\') THEN r."UNIT" ELSE 0 END) AS NET_SLSU,
                            SUM(CASE WHEN (r."ZWEEK" = \'',eopweek,'\') THEN r."ONHAND" ELSE 0 END) AS EOP_INV_UNIT,    
                            SUM(CASE WHEN (r."ZWEEK" = \'',eopweek,'\') THEN r."ONHANDCOST" ELSE 0 END) AS EOP_INV_COST,    
                            AVG(CASE WHEN (r."ZWEEK" BETWEEN \'',avginvBOP,'\' AND \'',avginvEOP,'\') THEN r."ONHAND" ELSE 0 END) AS BOP_INV_UNIT,  
                            AVG(CASE WHEN (r."ZWEEK" BETWEEN \'',avginvBOP,'\' AND \'',avginvEOP,'\') THEN r."ONHANDCOST" ELSE 0 END) AS BOP_INV_COST,              
                            SUM(CASE WHEN (r."ZWEEK" BETWEEN \'',receiptstart,'\' AND \'',receiptend,'\') THEN r."RECEIPU" ELSE 0 END) AS RECEIPT_UNITS,
                            SUM(CASE WHEN (r."ZWEEK" BETWEEN \'',receiptstart,'\' AND \'',receiptend,'\') THEN r."RECEIPC" ELSE 0 END) AS RECEIPT_COST


                            FROM "_SYS_BIC"."ZBHD.bw.bw2hana/XYZ_REPORT" As r
                            LEFT JOIN "_SYS_BIC"."ZBHD.bw.bw2hana/XYZ_MASTERMATERIAL" As mat On r."0MATERIAL" = mat."MATERIAL"

                            WHERE mat."DIVISION" IN (\'A\',\'B\',\'C\',\'D\',\'E\')
                            AND mat."MATL_TYPE" = \'RECENT\'


                            GROUP BY

                            mat."DIVISION_TXT",
                            mat."DEPARTMENT_TXT",
                            mat."CLASS_TXT",
                            mat."yz_abc1",
                            mat."yz_abc1_TXT",
                            mat."COLOR",
                            mat."COLOR_TXT"', sep = ''))
```

Comment: Do you have encoding issues in the result table? ie. special characters

Comment: You may try to use the odbc package.

Comment: (Sorry, not a solution for this problem, but ...) You may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. While there are security concerns about malicious [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI problems, even if it's a single data analyst running the query. Both of the `DBI` (with `odbc`) and `RODBC` packages support parameterized queries, either natively or via add-ons.

Comment: I have no idea if `RODBC` is the culprit here. It would be informative to run the same query with `DBI` and `odbc` to see if you can reproduce the problem. I think it'll be an easy thing to test, too: `ch <- DBI::dbConnect(...)` (same parameters) and `sales <- DBI::dbGetQuery(ch, paste(...))` (same query) should be a sufficient start. (And then look into parameterization.) Lacking that, have you tried playing with RODBC's `max=` argument to force the issue? (It defaults to 0 which should be no limit, just a thought.)

Comment: @GonzaloFallouxCosta no there is no encoding issues in the result table. The query runs and then only produce round number of observations. Like 200, 300, 800, 1000 etc.....

Comment: @user2332849, if I use ODBC pacakge can you tell me what would be the syntax for DB Connection? would it be like,    ch <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),"HANAxxxx",uid="xxxx",pwd="xxxxx")

Comment: ch <- dbConnect(odbc(), Driver = "SQL Server", Server = "xxx", Database = "xxx", Port = 1433, encoding = "windows-1252") works for a trusted connection.

Comment: @user2332849, As I'm connecting with SAP HANA I made below changes in the line    ch <- dbConnect(odbc(), Driver = "HDBODBC", Server = "xxxx.com:11111", Database = "HANAxxx", uid='xxxx' , pwd='xxxx', Port = 1433, encoding = "windows-1252").....However, I'm getting  Communication link failure;-10709 Connect failed (connect timeout expired)

Comment: @r2evans : I tried doing DBI::dbGetQuery but getting an error of "unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbGetQuery’ for signature ‘"RODBC", "character"’

Comment: I said `DBI` *and* `odbc`, neither work with `RODBC`. The intent of that suggestion was to determine if it is a problem with `RODBC` by removing it from the equation and using a relatively-equivalent method with `DBI` and `odbc` packages.

Comment: @Dhruv, it seems your odbc package is not being able to connect to the service. My first attempt would be to remove the port parameter, or, if it still doesn't works, to check whatever other port should be used in your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved an error by installing RJDBC package and installing jdbcDriver. and it worked perfectly fine...Thank you for all your help.

The below is a code to install driver and connecting to HANA

jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver", classPath="C:/Program Files/sap/hdbclient/ngdbc.jar")

ch <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver,"jdbc:sap://servername:port","username","password")

Comment: library (RODBC)
ch<-odbcConnect("SAP Data",uid= "DEVELOPER",pwd= "Sami@654321");
query<- paste0("Query")                                                                                                             i'm using this code can you tell me how can i use above line in my code to resolve this issue?

Comment: having same issue query doesn't return all records it only fetch limited records how can i fetch all records at a time ?